# CSS: Depress Dropdown grouped with Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using bootstrap to style a group of radio buttons that also include a dropdown.

When the user selects an option from the dropdown `OTHER` is not included as one of the radio buttons, so it looks like the last depressed radio button has been chosen when really `C | D | E` has been.

[image]

Is it possible to include the OTHER dropdown as one of the radio buttons so it looks depressed when the user selected C,D,E?

Codepen here if helpful: https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/qBdaZEJ

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='test']").change(function(){
      $("#results").text($("input[name='test']:checked").val());
    });
});

$(".dropdownitems").click(function () {
         var value = $(this).attr("href");
     document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = value   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id='RADIO' class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="testNONE" autocomplete="off" value="NONE">NONE
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="testA" autocomplete="off" value="A">A
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="test" id="testB" autocomplete="off" value="B">B
  </label>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <input type="radio" class="" name="test" id="OTHER" autocomplete="off">OTHER<span class="caret"></span>
    </label>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="C" class="dropdownitems" id="C">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="D" class="dropdownitems" id="D">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="E" class="dropdownitems" id="E">E</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: radio buttons should be used as form inputs, not buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that radio buttons are the good solution for this. You could just use "simple" buttons. Anyway, with bootstrap, you could add "active" to the button ( or radio button) class so that it will be shown as if it was pressed.
With single button

Pressed

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Click Me!</button>
```

Normal

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me!</button>
```

With your radio button it's the same

Pressed

```
<label class='btn btn-primary active'>
    <input type='radio' name='test' id='testA' autocomplete='off' value='A'>A
  </label>
```

Normal

```
<label class='btn btn-primary'>
    <input type='radio' name='test' id='testA' autocomplete='off' value='A'>A
  </label>
```

Example

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let pressedId
        let buttonsId = ["a", "b"] // List of the buttons which are always visible
        let dropDownsButtonId = ["c", "d", "e"] //List of the buttons of the dropdown
        $("button").click(function () {
            if (buttonsId.includes(this.id)) { //First "if" for "always visible" button
                changeClass(this.id)
            } else if (dropDownsButtonId.includes(this.id)) {//Second if for the button of the dropdown
                changeClass("dropDownMenuButton")
            }
        })

        function changeClass(id) {
            if (pressedId !== undefined)
                document.getElementById(pressedId).className = document.getElementById(pressedId).className.replace(" active", "")
            document.getElementById(id).className += " active"
            pressedId = id
        }
    })
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="a">a</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="b">b</button>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class='btn-group'>
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownMenuButton"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
            </button>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="c">c</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="d">d</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="e">e</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use buttons instead of a radio buttons then how do I show an option was selected (a button is depressed until a new one is selected)?

Comment: keep in memory the id of the last button pressed and in your onClick function do 3 actions ( change back the last button pressed class, change the button pressed class and save its id)

Comment: I've tried to apply what you've suggestion - would you mind looking over why this isn't working? https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/dyoppZK

Comment: I add an example in the first answer